# How logical operators works

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, unix, logical-operators

I tried below but it doesn't work. Throwing some errors. 
Exp1 or expr2 should evaluate first & at result should be evaluated with expr3 ( &&)

```
if [ "$val1" == "$val2" || "$val1" == "$val3" ]   && [ "$val4" > "$val5" ]
then
    echo "success"
elif [  "$val1" == "$val2" || "$val1" == "$val3" ]  && [ "$val4" < "$val5" ]
then
    echo "fail"
else
    echo "no result"
fi
fi
```

i tried as per suggestion, it throws error as

```
 ./temp.ksh[11]: 03/20/1996: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Fyi- that date is val1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might see different results based on the shell or version, eg: sh vs bash vs ash.
One example is some bash yield an error from [ [ (with a separating space), while [[ (without a separating space) is accepted.  Note there are different semantics within [ ] vs [[ ]] expressions.

Try dropping the outer space-separated [ and ] from your || expression.  Also check documentation for operator precedence to meet or confirm your needs.

Another issue is the use of redirects < and >.  Check your current directory for files named with the values from $val4 and $val5.  Switch to -gt and -lt for comparisons.

Also to avoid surprises: when using -gt and -lt, check what happens when an operand is empty or non-numeric.

=======

May 24 update:

The original post did not specify a shell; now using ksh, there's an issue with operator combos.  Looks like you'll need to use -o and -a with [ ] expressions or || and && with [[ ]] expressions.  After switching to [[ ]] and replacing > and <, this version works on jdoodle.com :

```
if [[ "$val1" == "$val2" || "$val1" == "$val3" ]] && [[ "$val4" -gt "$val5" ]]; then
    echo "success"
elif [[ "$val1" == "$val2" || "$val1" == "$val3" ]] && [[ "$val4" -lt "$val5" ]]; then
    echo "fail"
else
    echo "no result"
fi
```